# Changing function's scope

Tags: javascript

I recently discovered `with` in javascript to execute a block with an object as the current scope. I'm curious if there is some javascript magic to do the same thing with a function and call it in a different scope.

Example:

```
var scope = { foo: 'bar' },
    foo   = 'baz';

function func(){
  return foo;
}

with(scope){
  foo;    // foo is 'bar'
  func(); // foo is still 'baz' 
}
```

In the example, `with` changes the scope of the variable `foo`, but the function still uses the scope outside of `with` where it was defined. Any suggestions for how to alter or rebind the scope of a function?

Comment: Just FYI: _"Use of the with statement is not recommended, as it may be the source of confusing bugs and compatibility issues. [...] Using with is not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5 strict mode."_ -- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short - **YES**

With is special, it does [dynamic binding](http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/20/what-is-lexical-scoping/). It creates confusing bugs which is why `with` statements do not run in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode).

**However** no one said we can't have a little fun. We can't change the closure variables the function has, however - we can exploit JavaScript's highly dynamic nature to read the function's source code and generate a new binding. It's not core language or generic, but for the case you asked it's certainly doable.

Here is a sample for the very basic case you asked (no nested closures, no parameters etc) . While you can't alter the closure, you can declare a new function that runs the same code of the other one. Let me make one thing very clear - this is a dirty hack here ;)

```
var scope = {foo: 'bar'},
             foo = 'baz';


var func = function func() {
    return foo;
}
// here, `foo` is closed over by the outer foo and it is 'baz'

document.body.innerHTML += " " + func(); // foo is still 'baz'

// foo is bar, since it's a different function here:
document.body.innerHTML += " " + withFunc({foo:"bar"},func); 

function withFunc(obj, func) {
    //declare a new function
    return new Function("obj", // with a parameter obj
          "with(obj){\n " +  // do `with` on that parameter
          "return "+func+"()\n}")(obj); // invoke and return original function 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/42YX4/

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I figured it was a bad idea to actually do. It was more of a curiosity about whether it was possible. I completely forgot about the function constructor, that's a great solution.

Answer (score 2):

In short - **NO**

With is special, it does [dynamic binding](http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/20/what-is-lexical-scoping/). It creates confusing bugs which is why `with` statements do not run in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode).

The function in your case [closes over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) `foo`. Once the function is declared there is no way to change which `foo` it references.

---

If we have to be precise:

Section [10.4.3](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3) of the language specification describes "Entering Function Code", the interesting thing here is:

> Let localEnv be the result of calling NewDeclarativeEnvironment passing the value of the [[Scope]] internal property of F as the argument.

This happens after we figure `this` out and before we set the scope to localEnv we just found. Now what is this `[[Scope]]` ?

> [[Scope]] - Lexical Environment - A lexical environment that defines the environment in which a Function object is executed. Of the standard built-in ECMAScript objects, only Function objects implement [[Scope]].

This means that the scope of the function is decided beforehand, and not based on dynamic context :)

Comment: Related and interesting, but deprecated and certainly not a part of the language - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Parent

Comment: It's interesting that "this" is set before the scope. Considering "this" is easily modified with apply/call, I'd expect scope to be set first since it's static. Thanks for the thorough explanation!